# Exporting Slices from Sketch results in some slices exporting original size rather than export size

Tags: export, sketch-app

I have a sketch file with many export sizes.

[image]

The original canvas is 1024x1024 and it's a slice.  For some reason, certain versions (like 152w) export correctly with 152x152 pixels.  But others export with original size.

What would cause Sketch to export this canvas incorrectly for certain sizes?

Comment: Sketch team is looking at this.